# mismatched input 'from'. expecting: 'on', 'using' in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Facing this error when using the below code

```
SELECT AM.MemoryDescription from universal_final_circle_sg_Assets  
 

LEFT JOIN (

        SELECT DISTINCT AP2.AssetID,

            SUBSTRING(
            (

                SELECT ', ' + TRIM(STR(CountNo)) + ' x' + Capacity AS char
                FROM (

    SELECT AssetID, COUNT(*) AS CountNo, Max(CHARACTER_LENGTH(Capacity / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 5, 2) + ' GB RAM ' + Type) AS Capacity

                    FROM universal_final_circle_sg_AssetMemoryModules

                    WHERE SeparatedAsset = 0
                    
                  GROUP BY AssetID, Capacity, Type
                ) AP1
                WHERE AP1.AssetID = AP2.AssetID
                -- FOR XML PATH ('')
            ), 3, 1000) [MemoryDescription]
        FROM (
            SELECT AssetID, COUNT(*) AS CountNo, Max(TRIM(Capacity / 1024 / 1024 / 1024),TRIM(5), 2) + ' GB ' + Type)) AS Capacity
                 FROM  universal_final_circle_sg_AssetMemoryModules
                WHERE SeparatedAsset = 0
                GROUP BY AssetID, Capacity, Type
            ) AP2
        ) AM ON universal_final_circle_sg_Assets.ID = AM.AssetID
```

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would say that `+ ' GB ' + Type)) AS Capacity` has 2 extra parenthesis in it)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).